# Python log in website once for multiple site scraping

Tags: python

I want to scrape data from a website.
The Python code below works fine for 1 id. But for each id, the code logs in ONCE. Thus if I want to download data for 100id, the code will need to log in 100 times.

Is there anyway to log in just one time, and followed by a scraping loop to download data for multiple ids?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# URL and id ---------------------------------
company = 313055
url = 'https://www.capitaliq.com/CIQDotNet/Estimates/CIQ/consensus.aspx?CompanyId={}&dataVendorId=1'
bot = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
bot.get(url.format(company))

# Log in -------------------------------------
bot.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys("")
pwd = bot.find_element_by_id('password')
pwd.send_keys('')
pwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Download data ------------------------------
soup = BeautifulSoup(bot.page_source, 'lxml')
```

UPDATED:
So the solution is to use the main page url, and log in.
Then putting company into search box.
This case, you dont need to login again and again

Comment: Is it possible to go to different id urls without having to login multiple times manually? Because if so, then explaining how that works will help us better understand the problem.

Comment: I can (1): log in the website, type company code in searchbox, search. yes, it login just once. OR (2) after the above code run, the page is opened. I can manually copy and paste a new link (change id) and the new company still load. Not sure if this answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: you can use selenium to use the searchbox, rather than updating the url, no?

Comment: Yes, when I change url in the above code to ``` url = 'https://www.capitaliq.com' ``` I can log in

Comment: Instead of updating the url for each id, use selenium to use the searchbox.

Comment: You are right, it is how I should do. Using the search rather than url. It is the first code I work on the topic. ``` bot.find_element_by_id('SearchTopBar').send_keys("BAC")
firm = bot.find_element_by_id('SearchTopBar')
firm.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) ```

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: Yes my problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: So the solution is to use the main page url, and log in. Then putting company into search box. This case, you dont need to login again and again

```
# LOG ON TO Capitaliq.com
url = 'https://www.capitaliq.com'
bot = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
bot.get(url.format(company))

bot.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys("")
pwd = bot.find_element_by_id('password')
pwd.send_keys('')
pwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

tickers_list=[19049,24937]
for ticker in tickers_list:
    print('**********', ticker)
    good=0
    
    # Enter Firm information
    bot.find_element_by_id('SearchTopBar').send_keys(ticker)
    bot.find_element_by_id('SearchTopBar').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```